# Google analytics showing hundreds of views for page that doesn't exist

Tags: google-analytics

I recently signed up for a google analytics account in anticipation of a new site I'm putting together. The site has not been published, and the tracking script has not been put in the code yet.

Somehow after logging back in to grab the tracking code, it's showing I've already had 275 views in the past month. How is this possible???

Comment: Please add a screen shot of the specific report you are speaking of and also a screen shot of the Acquisition >> All Traffic >> Referrals report? (The Referrals report might indicate referral spam.)

Comment: Likely the activity of ghost referrals. These resources are good resources to help you out: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/, http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/03/19/eliminating-dumb-ghost-referral-traffic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are very likely ghost referrals sent by spammers targeting random GA property IDs (which explains why you see them even before your Web site is live). Since you are setting up a new site, probably the easiest way to get rid of them is to create a new Web property so that you get an ID not ending with `-1`. The reason is that this type of spam is only targeted at the first property in an account.

If you want to get more information about how referrer spam works and alternative solutions to eliminate it, here is an article I wrote some time ago:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/21/referrer-spam.html